# How to get SAML Signing Certificate data using Microsoft graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Http requests to retrieve data from Azure active directory, my goal is to retrieve data about all certificates and secrets in Azure Ad applications so when i call: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications`i get data about the applications including applications certificates and secrets. but there is one missing data : the SAML Signing Certificate, see below :

[image]

I've tried to get serviceprincipal data through: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals but still, data about the single sign-on saml certificate is not listed, how can i access this data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAML certificate info is available from the `servicePrincipals` endpoint, but not the `applications` endpoint.

You'll find relevant info in the `KeyCredentials` and the `preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint` properties.

**Portal view**

[image]

**Graph API Example output**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals/$entity",
    "id": "b1d98f31-0d9e-4deb-b9d7-a9b65a9dc35b",
    "appId": "c2fa0ce8-1894-4e25-aa85-cd3880d2f849",
    "keyCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": "ND35AAdHR6SwZl73ExNO7aGzDbb2NBchauiGFOF4dto=",
            "displayName": "CN=Microsoft Azure Federated SSO Certificate",
            "endDateTime": "2025-06-02T04:49:26Z",
            "key": null,
            "keyId": "2e5cf0c3-a2af-43ff-902f-5915a5c1739a",
            "startDateTime": "2022-06-02T04:49:25Z",
            "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
            "usage": "Verify"
        },
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": "ND35AAdHR6SwZl73ExNO7aGzDbb2NBchauiGFOF4dto=",
            "displayName": "CN=Microsoft Azure Federated SSO Certificate",
            "endDateTime": "2025-06-02T04:49:26Z",
            "key": null,
            "keyId": "d9828f8c-551a-4e22-9e99-ae4559eff713",
            "startDateTime": "2022-06-02T04:49:25Z",
            "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
            "usage": "Sign"
        }
    ],
    "preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint": "BAE149EA92FBF748FABE89EEB150F9D65BE4F676",
}
```

**KeyCredentials**

For each certificate you see in the Portal, you'll see 2 objects, which corresponds to the public and private certificate. The public certificate is the key where the `Usage` property is `Verify`. The private certificate you don't see when you're viewing from the Portal.

**PreferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint**

This is the thumbprint of the certificate which is currently active. You'll notice that the thumbprint is NOT in the `KeyCredentials` info. Only when you first assign a certificate is the thumbprint included in the `KeyCredentials`.

Comment: Thank you for your response sounds obvious but this id : "id": "b1d98f31-0d9e-4deb-b9d7-a9b65a9dc35b", is the id of the serviceprincipal, how did you got it ? how can i get the serviceprincipal of a specific app ? can you please show me the whole http request that yous sent

Comment: You can make a request using the service principal name like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=DisplayName eq 'app-01'`

Comment: @scottwtang, since the thumbprint is not included in the response, how can we identify which certificate is currently active? With what do we have to match `PreferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint`?

Comment: @pinkpan Did u find out how to identify the current active certificate from the list of certs in the response?